# How to find on a string the first occurrence of a text that begins with a word and ends with another word

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, having a string like *'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit'* i have to find the text that begins with ***'porro'*** and ends with ***'qui'***. Ideally with a function like `findPhrase(str, first_word, second_word) // Returns the whole text if found, else -1`.

```
function findPhrase(str, first_word, second_word) {
    // ...
}

var my_string = "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit",
    example_1 = findPhrase(my_string, 'porro', 'qui'), // returns 'porro quisquam est qui'
    example_2 = findPhrase(my_string, 'hello', 'world'); // returns -1
```

Comment: Have you tried: `/\bporro\b.*\bqui\b/`

Comment: And what is the expected output from `Neque *porro quisquam porro est qui* dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit`? `porro quisquam porro est qui` or `porro est qui`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findPhrase(str, first_word, second_word) {
    var reg = new RegExp("\\b"+first_word+".*?"+second_word+"\\b","g");    
    return str.match(reg); // it's an array ,if only one string,just get the first index
}
```

OutPut:

```
["porro quisquam est qui"]
```